# Run batch file as administrator in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to run the java code which runs a batch file. But without administrator access I am unable to run this

This throws error:-

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users/Desktop/ex.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code:-

```
String cmds[] = {"C:\\Users/Desktop/ex.bat"};
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(cmds);
```

So how can I include administrator access in my java code ?

Comment: Try launching your java application as an administrator.

Comment: @Arnaud Didn't worked

Comment: Path's are wrong `C:\\Users/Desktop/ex.bat`

Comment: @Aris I have tried with all possible way.